# QVBoxLayout push to the top with spacer

Tags: qt

I would like to add push buttons to the layout. The newest item would be on the top of the layout.

I also would like position the buttons to the top, thus I am using QSpacerItem.

Here is what I have tried so far.

**Constructor:**

```
//frame is a QFrame
lVertical = new QVBoxLayout(frame); //private variable
lVertical->setMargin(0);
lVertical->setSpacing(0);

auto verticalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(10, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
lVertical->addItem(verticalSpacer);

connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::addToLayout);
```

**Function:**

```
void MainWindow::addToLayout() {
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(frameSlider);
    button->setText(QString::number(i));
    ++i; //private variable
    layoutVertical->addWidget(button);
}
```

Currently I add like this:

[image]

But I would like to add like this:

[image]

Comment: `lVertical` or `layoutVertical`?

Comment: `lVertical ` sorry I have wrote it wrongly

Comment: There is still layoutVertical in addToLayout, but it is already irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have placed a spacer at the beginning so it will stretch all the widgets down.

One possible solution is to add a stretch and then insert an element before, You should not use `QSpacerItem`:

```cpp
// constructor
layoutVertical = new QVBoxLayout(frame);
layoutVertical->setMargin(0);
layoutVertical->setSpacing(0);
layoutVertical->addStretch();
```

```cpp
void MainWindow::addToLayout() {
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton();
    layoutVertical->insertWidget(0, button);
}
```

Comment: This is still not good, edit your answer to `layoutVertical->insertWidget(0, button);`, because the newest item should be on the top.

Comment: @zayts I hadn't noticed the order, just the fact that the buttons were at the bottom.

Comment: That not a problem, the main thing was to not use spaceritem, and use addStretch instead.